# LibGDX: Drawing shapes using Scene2D

Tags: java, opengl, libgdx

I'm using the `Scene2D` framework of LibGDX. In my game, I also want to draw `Rectangles`. Since `Stage` only possesses a `Batch`, I created a custom `Stage` which owns a `ShapeRenderer`.

The `Actor` passes his x, y, width and height to ShapeRenderer which then incorrectly draws the `Rectangle` around the `Actor`. I'm using a virtual dimensions of 20x12.

The `x`, `y`, `width` and `height` are **unchanged**. I've set the `ProjectionMatrix` to my stage's `Camera`. Help!

```
public void setProjectionMatrix(Camera camera) {
    shapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
}
```

[image: ShapeRenderer incorrect drawing]

Comment: Now I can not prove it, but maybe, some of this can help `stage.getBatch().getProjectionMatrix();`
`stage.getCamera().projection.cpy();`
`stage.getCamera().combined.cpy();`

Comment: You should to provide better description and some of code. Because I have no idea what is and what exactly have to be on a screenshot.

What actors do you use? What changes you made to stage?